# Conversion to .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net

I recently started maintaining a .Net 1.1 project and would like to 
convert it to .Net 3.5.

Any tips to share on reducing code by making use of new features?

As a first attempt, I would like to convert a bunch of static helper functions.

**Update**: The main reason why I am converting is to learn new features like static classes, LINQ etc. Just for my own use at least for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [static classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(VS.80).aspx) (C# 2.0 feature) to rewrite old helper functions.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest starting by migrating to .NET 2.0 features, first.

My first step would be to slowly refactor to move all the collections to generic collections.  This will help tremendously, and ease the migration into the .NET 3.5 features, especially with LINQ.  It should also have a nice impact on your performance, since any collections of value types will perform better.

Be wary in this of converting HashTables to Dictionary<T,U>, since the behavior is different in some cases, but otherwise, ArrayList->List<T>, etc are easy, useful conversions.

After that, moving helpers to static classes, and potentially extension methods, would be a good next step to consider.  This can make the code more readable.

Comment: +1 for generic collections, I was going to suggest it.  I think that one change should be among the first changes made during the migration.

Comment: by List I think you mean ArrayList.

Comment: useful tips. i dont have any collections though. just Datasets..:(

Comment: @Chris S: I'd look into moving your static helper functions to static classes and extension methods, where appropriate, then.  That would be a good first step.  Also, I'd be suprised if there are NO collections - ArrayList, Arrays, etc, that wouldn't benefit.  Most code has them scattered throughout

Answer (score 1):

If you can swing it, the easiest way I've found to do this is using **Visual Studio 2008** and **[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)**. ReSharper will show you, via some kindly visible notation, where you can improve your code. Then it will show you a keyboard shortcut Alt+Enter to "fix" your code.

ReSharper also has a feature called "Cleanup Code" that will will do some of the refactoring for you.

Comment: YES!  Resharper will tell you all over where you might want to change.  +1

Comment: sorry. I dont want to use any tools which automate this. I feel it wont help in my learning experience. just my thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Why convert at all, .Net 1.1 is fully compatible with .Net 3.5, so you should not find any breaking changes when you migrate. If you need to refactor an area because it has problems or you wish to extend it somehow then I would consider migrating to use newer features, but otherwise why touch it and risk breaking it?

**Edit** As this is a learning excercise rather than changing production code I'd revise my views somewhat; this is probably a good way to learn new approaches. I'd certainly look at LINQ. In places where the old code was iterating through lists or manipulating XML or data from a DB see if you can re-write using LINQ instead.

Comment: i would like to learn new features. this is just for my use. thought i will learn new features by learning where to apply it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Breaking old code wind you no friends (I found that out myself!!), but if it's for your own use the go for it... I'll edit to add some thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start by "convert[ing] a bunch of static helper functions", then you'll want to check out [**extension methods**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

It's likely that you can use them to make your code simpler and more readable.